# How to connect 3 External Monitors in Macbook Pro 13 2017 without Touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

I am currently connected to 2 external monitors + the Macbook Display.
I want to add additional monitors, so that I can have 3 external monitors along with the Macbook's display.

I know that you can only connect 2 external monitor for the 13' Macbook Pro as per [this](https://hengedocks.com/blogs/henge-docks-blog/how-to-run-external-displays-with-your-usb-c-thunderbolt-3-macbook) link, but you can connect an additional monitor using a USB display adapter.

I bought [this](https://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-VGA-DVI-HDMI-Adapter~MDP2VGDVHD) adapter, but I am unable to connect to a 3rd monitor using either VGA, Display, or DVI.

Does anyone know how to connect more monitors using a USB display adapter?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple you have only [two USB-C/Thunderbolt](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) ports on that model of Macbook Pro.

The adapter your linked to is a Mini-Display Port to DVI adapter. your Mac does not have a mini DisplayPort, nor does it have a third port to plug it into.

Additionally the specifications say that it will support up to two external monitors. The highest resolution being of the 4K variety, so some good sized monitors, but only two of them. And as you have only two ports kinda hard to use a third adapter to connect a third monitor, *even if the Mac supported three monitors, which it does not.*

Granted you can daisy chain USB-C/Thunderbolt monitors and theoretically dasiychain three monitors that way but you still run into the spec that says it only supports two.

So no you can't use that adapter and you can't connect more than two monitors, according to the Apple specs.

Comment: I have put wrong adapter in the link.
I tried with following adapter?

https://www.cdw.com/product/StarTech.com-Travel-A-V-Adapter-HDMI-to-DisplayPort-VGA-or-DVI-1920x1200/4187677?cm_cat=Transactional&cm_ite=AS400_Shipping_Conf-_-Body-_-Browse_Products-_-&cm_pla=EMTRAN006adu0000P0000&cm_ven=Email&etsi=13109980&etsu=200932367

Comment: I have put wrong adapter in the link.
I tried with following adapter?

https://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/hdmi-to-displayport-vga-dvi-adapter~HD2DPVGADVI

Comment: The adapter does not matter, this Mac supports only two external monitors. Check the specs at Apple.com or buy everything you think you need and try it. But make sure there is a good return policy.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you need [USB display adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CSG7TUC) not DisplayPort adapter.
This Mac GPU supports up to two external monitors, but USB display adapter has its own simple GPU.
The main con is very limited resolution and refresh rate of such adapters.